# Creat an image from Google Compute Engine instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to replicate a new instance from my current instance in Google Compute Engine (following Google instruction: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#create_an_image_from_a_root_persistent_disk).

In step 3 (Terminate your instance), I am following the instruction ($ gcloud compute instances delete example-instance --keep-disks boot). However, it still asks me whether I want to completely delete the instance:

*The following instances will be deleted. Attached disks configured to 
be auto-deleted will be deleted unless they are attached to any other 
instances. Deleting a disk is irreversible and any data on the disk 
will be lost. Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  n*

Am I still able to recover the instance or continue to create the image of my current instance as Google's instruction? If any body has try to replicate Google Compute Engine, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: try " --keep-disks all " option.

Comment: What connection does the problem have to Google App Engine?!  Please edit the Q, either to clarify where GAE enters the picture, or, I suspect, to remove the totally-irrelevant tag, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this command on my account and deleted my instance using " --keep-disks boot ". This option keeps the boot disk despite the warning message which says "Attached disks configured to be auto-deleted will be deleted....."

You can also use Developers Console, uncheck "Delete boot disk when instance is deleted" under your instance properties and then delete the instance from there.

Comment: Thank you Kamran! Yes, it works. They still keep the boot disk despite of the warning!